# Fixing misspelling of "swords and sorcery" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, retagging

It's almost always used as "sword and sorcery", only a single sword. The current tag "swords and sorcery" is a misspelling.

I am strongly in favor of correcting it to the actual term.

Comment: Do you have any proof that one is prevalent? Google n-grams, for instance?

Comment: Not that I'm in disagreement; Wikipedia agrees with you, for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_and_sorcery it's just that I like to some proof before we undertake this.

Comment: Also, a mod could do this in one fell swoop, leaving the misspelling as a synonym.

Comment: Of course: It's about [nine times as common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Sword+and+Sorcery%2CSwords+and+Sorcery&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1960&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CSword%20and%20Sorcery%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsword%20and%20sorcery%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSword%20and%20Sorcery%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSword%20and%20sorcery%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CSwords%20and%20Sorcery%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bswords%20and%20sorcery%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSwords%20and%20Sorcery%3B%2Cc0) in the singular than in the plural.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not all that familiar with this term, but a quick check on Wikipedia suggests that ["sword and sorcery"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_and_sorcery) refers to the subgenre of fantasy while [*Swords and Sorcery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swords_and_Sorcery) refers to a particular work within this subgenre.

Since [all the questions with the tag on this site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swords-and-sorcery) refer to the subgenre rather than the specific work, I've changed the tag name to [sword-and-sorcery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sword-and-sorcery). If we ever get questions about the specific work, we may have to think again, since I'm not sure if the system will allow two such similar tag names.

Comment: The *system* will perfectely allow both tags (though, it might complain when a mortal user tries to create it for the first time). The question is if the *community* is fine with it in light of possible confusions.