# What's up with the [sword-and-sorcery] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see that we have the tag [sword-and-sorcery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sword-and-sorcery), currently with 8 questions - 6 of which are [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), the other two closed as off topic.

We previously [renamed this tag](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10389/33591). But what should it actually be used for? Generally, our genre tags are for questions about the genre itself. But this tag doesn't seem to *have* any questions like that.

How should we be using it? (Do we even need it at all?)

Comment: The usage is a duplicate of Rand's answer in the linked meta. We need it as it's clearly being used on story-id. Maybe the tag needs to be made more aware so that people can start adding on all the other relevant questions that should have it. Subgenre tags should not be removed because of a lack of usage. We should be preparing for the growth of our site and the tags should reflect that. What is small now may become useful in the future for users to find storys specific to `[sword-and-sorcery]`

Answer (score 4):

I think we're using it correctly as is. Adding a subgenre to an identification question can really narrow down the possible results, or point someone to a better resource during their research.

---

As an aside, I think we have an opportunity to discuss ways to boost our usage of genre tags, so they're more widely used. The lack of usage could be blamed on a number of reasons:

- Many ID questions come from new users, who don't know about our wealth of tagging options

  - **Solution**: Prompt them to add genre tags as part of our story ID guidance
- We don't retag answered story-id questions once an answer is accepted

  - **Solution**: Decide on some types of tags to add back to solved ID questions (such as most-relevant subgenre and a tag for the specific work)
- We don't have a good resource for looking at all our genres, or a way to see just genres

  - **Solution**: Make a Meta FAQ post (or an answer on the story ID FAQ) that lists our genre tags and their wikis, so we can point users to something tangible
  - **And/or**: Rename our genre tags to all have `-genre` appended to them, so searching "genre" in the tag box brings them all up

Perhaps it's worth opening a new discussion on these points. We've recently, but informally, established some different tagging guidelines for our "major" tags. DC, Marvel and *Lord of the Rings* universes all had major retagging efforts, and they have different (informal) stewards who help maintain the tagging system. [There's even some formal support for this system](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11199/31178) based on a recent meta about a Harry Potter related tag.

If we applied those principles to story identification questions, I think we could:

- Increase tag usage and consistency
- Improve our ability to find possible duplicates
- Get the side-bonus of benefiting people who would say "Yes" to the question: `Is it reasonable to assume some people might want to know about just that genre?` (modified from the 2nd bullet on other linked meta answer)

Comment: Re your second bullet point - we have an [existing policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/671/31394) not to retag story-ID questions based on the accepted answer. If you're proposing to change this policy, I'd be in favour of keeping it for the reasons I gave [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/431/17)

Comment: @Randal'Thor There's been discussion other times about changing it. I'd be in favor of it because: 1) The question _is_ about that work, they just couldn't remember the work (hence the question) 2) The double-take is silly, because if people know the site policy (and can see the edit histories), the proper tag wouldn't be incongruous 3) It wouldn't really effect searchability because the magic `-[*-identification]` search parameter  would filter out all ID questions (and someone might actually search for all ID ones, if they know the book better and can improve existing answers).

Comment: Regardless, changing the policy isn't what I'm suggesting _here_. This answer is mainly a "This tag is functioning as intended", but I'm suggesting we need to have a discussion on what to do about Story ID in general [(which I've suggested before)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10956/should-we-admit-that-story-identification-breaks-tagging-conventions-and-make-ne). My above comment is more to capture my current thoughts in case the discussion comes up.